# Print the docString of the currently running python script from an imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I desire the following behaviour

```
# module.py
""" module's docString """

def foo():
   print(??something??)
   do other stuff`
```

```
# script.py
""" Scripts docString """

from module import foo

foo()

do otherstuff
```

Now when I run `python script.py` I would like the call to foo() to print the docString of `script.py`

I have tried

```
# module.py
""" module's docString """

def foo():
   print(__doc__)
   do other stuff`
```

But this prints the docString of `module.py`

Comment: Python is statically scoped. `module.foo` doesn't receive any information about which scope it is called in, and `__doc__` refers to its *own* module's global variables.

Comment: Perhaps I have been unclear....
I agree it is module's docString that is printed.
I wish to print script's docString.

Comment: No, I misread the question; I've deleted my old useless comment.

Comment: Ok, no problem. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sys.modules` to get a reference to the `__main__` module, whatever module that might be. With that, you can access its `__doc__` attribute.

```
# module.py
""" module's docString """

import sys


def foo():
   print(sys.modules['__main__'].__doc__)
```

Comment: Perfect. That does exactly what I want. Thank you. Will accept as answer.
(minor typo: should be sys.modules in last line, wouldn't let me make the edit...)

Comment: Note that this will *not* work if you call it from the `__main__` module itself.

Comment: Sure it does; you just have to actually *call* `foo` (which is not shown in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

The docstring is stored in the module's `__doc__` global.

```
def foo():
   print("something")
   import script
   print(script.__doc__)
```

Comment: This probably works but not for my use case as foo must be imported into a variety of scripts so must be more generalised. Thanks.